# define register alias for register

Tags: gcc, assembly, microblaze

How to define register alias in assembler file ('.S') for microblaze?
So I could write instructions with this alias like

```
addi    ctx, r0, 0x08
```

for ARM it was `ctx .req r12`. 
Neither `.req` or `.register` works for microblaze.

File is compiled with GCC.

Comment: compiled with gcc or assembled with gas?

Comment: with gcc (mb-gcc), asm (eg mb-as) gives the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe not ideal but as GCC preprocesses assembly files so you can simply use C macro:

```
#define ctx r12
```

Comment: No, the same. Assembler messages:
Error: unknown opcode "ctx" <\n>
Error: register expected, but saw 'ctx,4' <\n>
Warning: ignoring operands: ,4  <\n>

Comment: @user3124812 Do you assemble via as or gcc driver? Only the latter will preprocess code and only if it has .S extension.

Comment: It's 'gcc' and extension is capital '.S'

Comment: `SCons` is used to build the project. While the file indeed has 'capital' `.S` extension, in scons script file list it was listed with 'small' `.s`. This screw up 'GCC'. `ctx .req r12` syntax still doesn't work after fix